# image/svg+xml with ContentViewClient in android 4.4

Tags: android

In android 4.4, browser used ContentViewClient without WebviewClient. 
before android 4.4, I can make

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { var s=document.createElement('style');s.innerHTML = '@font-face{font-family:Padauk;src:url(\"padauk.svg\")format(\"svg\");}body,p,div,h1,h2,h3,input,textarea{font-family:Padauk! important;}';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontFamily = \"Padauk\"})()");

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            //@Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest ( WebView view, String url) {
                if(url.contains("padauk.svg")){
                    return  new WebResourceResponse("image/svg+xml", "UTF-8", getFileInputStream(view, "padauk.svg"));
                }
                return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
            }

            private InputStream getFileInputStream(WebView paramWebView, String paramString)
            {
              try
              {
                InputStream localInputStream = getBaseContext().getAssets().open(paramString);
                return localInputStream;
              }
              catch (IOException localIOException) {}
              return null;

            }

        });
```

I don't know how to make WebResourceResponse("image/svg+xml", "UTF-8".. with ContentViewClient.
Please help me.
Thanks and Best Regards